# Convergence/Divergence of series with complex numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

In what set of complex numbers does these series $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ convergence/divergence? If series convergences is the convergence steady (uniform?) within the convergence area.

$(a)$ $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n z}{n}$

\begin{align}
r&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigg| \frac{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}}{\frac{(-1)^n}{n}}\Bigg| \\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigg| \frac{(-1)^n (-1)^1}{n+1} \frac{n}{(-1)^n}\Bigg| \\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigg|\frac{-n}{n+1}\Bigg|=|-1|=1
\end{align}

So it converges for $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}$ when $|z|<1$. Doesn't this mean it diverges if $|z|>1$?

$(b)$ $a_n=nz^n$

\begin{align}
r=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigg| \frac{(n+1)z^{n+1}}{nz^n} \Bigg| \\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigg| \frac{(n+1)z^nz}{nz^n} \Bigg| \\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigg| \frac{nz+z}{n} \Bigg| \\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigg| z+\frac zn  \Bigg| \\
&=|z|
\end{align}
Converges when $|z|<1$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

$(c)$ $a_n=\frac{z^n}{n}$

\begin{align}
r&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{|z^n|}}{\sqrt[n]{n}} \\
&=\frac{|z|}{1}=|z|
\end{align}
Converges when $|z|<1$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the question. It is about series $\sum_{n\ge 1}a_n$ and not about the convergence of the sequence $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n.$

Comment: Hmmm. What approach should I use then?

Comment: You may find useful the convergence tests in this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty }\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=1$$
where $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$. Then the serie converge for all $z\in\mathbb C$ such that $|z|<1$.

Comment: I edited my OG post. Can I use this ratio test on the others as well?

Comment: what is OG ? Of course, you can ;-)

Comment: original post. I tried what you did there to $a_n=nz^n$ and it didn't work out so well. Root test gave me $r=z$.

Comment: (b) and (c) came to the same result $r=z$

Comment: It doesn't !! $a_n=n$ and not $nz^n$. But you can also take $a_n=nz^n$, then $$\lim_{n\to\infty }\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=|z|$$ and you know by d'Alembert theorem that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$ converge if and only if $$\lim_{n\to\infty }\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\rho<1$$ who gives precisely in your exemple that $|z|<1$.

Comment: Ahh. Because $|z+z/n|$ has limit $|z|$ when $n\to \infty$.

Comment: there is absolutely no correlation. What I call d'Alembert Theorem, in english is in fact **Ratio test**. You will find more information here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test

Comment: Thank you. I think I got it.